# Открыть скачаный репозиторий в IDE

Tags: git

Скачал проект с github. В Intelige Idea выбрал File / Open / папка с проектом. Проект открылся, но не запускается!

Comment: Очень жаль, а вот у меня отлично запускается

Comment: как вы запускаете? Просто открываете папку с проектом, или создаете на его основе новый? Только когда я новый создаю у меня пропадает файл pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы запустить приложение через IntelliJ IDEA необходимо создать новую конфигурацию запуска.

В верхнем правом углу, есть выбор конфигураций

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут необходимо выбрать класс, который запускается, выбрать папку или модуль, выбрать JDK и дополнительные параметры запуска. После чего можно запускать через Run или Debug.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]